# Win 7, Dell; no sound to headphones when on vimeo or youtube, vlc works ok

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones, vimeo

I'm running Win7 on a Dell.

I have sound working to headphones on vlc but no sound when on Vimeo or YouTube. Before a system reinstall by a professional due to a virus I would be prompted to acknowledge that I had plugged in my headphones and to close speakers and all was good. Sound in Control Panel doesn't show headphones and Realtec HD Audio Manager in Control Panel doesn't open.

Comment: I'd bet $20 that this is no virus. To be sure, can you tell us what your device manager says about your sound hardware (don't know WTF I mean? Look here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000833.htm)? It'll be under the group 'Sound, video and game controllers'. If it doesn't tell you anything, is their a big yellow icon next to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Check your volume control settings for Firefox and Flash. Make sure volume is not down or muted. From your notification bar, click volume control -> Mixer.